# SQL Server Agent Job - where to find Package Source

Tags: sql

I am trying to figure out where an SSIS package is located for a SQL Server Agent Job.
I have had to take over the administration with limited knowledge of SQL Server so please excuse my ignorance.
I see two Jobs under SQL Server Agent Job in Object Explorer.
When I right click on one of them and select Properties, under Job Properties, I go to "Steps" and see one step. I highlight the Step and select "Edit". Under that window, in the General section and General Tab, I see \LoadPackagexyz under the Package field. When I click the browse button, it shows up under SSIS Packages folder tree.

My question - where do I find this "LoadPackagexyz" package to view its properties?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried connecting to the server in question through SSMS with Server type in the connection dialog set to "Integration Services"?  That might be the key!